# google drive api v2 get me authentication error

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

i am using c# language the service get me exception

> "failed to launch browser with https //accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth"

the steps that i followed :

1. Enable Google drive api service from google console developer
2. Generate client id, client secret (i tried two type of OAuth Client id type {Web Application and Other}
   the two type get me the same exception

My code is :

```
    public File InsertFile(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        // File's metadata
        File body = new File();
        body.Title = "my title";
        body.Description = "my description";
        body.MimeType = "image/jpg";

        // File's content.
        System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

        try
        {

            var credential = Authentication();

            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = string.Format("{0} elfeedback-project", System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName),
            });

            FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "image/jpg");
            request.UploadAsync();

            File file = request.ResponseBody;

            return file;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }`
```

---

### the Authentication get exception :

```
    `public UserCredential Authentication()
    {
        string[] scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                   DriveService.Scope.DriveFile,
        };

        UserCredential credential;
        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = "my client id",
            ClientSecret = "my client secret"
        },
        scopes,
        "myGmail Account that authenticated (client id ,client secret)",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore("Drive.Auth.Store")).Result;

        return credential;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the code for installed applcations.  The code is trying to open a new browser window for consent on the server rather than on the users browser.

```
new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
            {
                ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = "PUT_CLIENT_ID_HERE",
                    ClientSecret = "PUT_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE"
                },
                Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                DataStore = new FileDataStore("Drive.Api.Auth.Store")
            });
```

## update

If you want to upload to an account that you control then you should look into useing a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).   Service accounts are dummy users they have their own google drive account which you can upload to.  You can not use a web view to see what is on this account.    You will need to create service account credentials not OAuth credentials.

```
public static DriveService AuthenticateServiceAccount(string serviceAccountEmail, string serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, string[] scopes)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath))
                    throw new Exception("Path to the service account credentials file is required.");
                if (!File.Exists(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath))
                    throw new Exception("The service account credentials file does not exist at: " + serviceAccountCredentialFilePath);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceAccountEmail))
                    throw new Exception("ServiceAccountEmail is required.");                

                // For Json file
                if (Path.GetExtension(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath).ToLower() == ".json")
                {
                    GoogleCredential credential;
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                             .CreateScoped(scopes);
                    }

                    // Create the  Analytics service.
                    return new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                        ApplicationName = "Drive Service account Authentication Sample",
                    });
                }
                else if (Path.GetExtension(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath).ToLower() == ".p12")
                {   // If its a P12 file

                    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
                    var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                    {
                        Scopes = scopes
                    }.FromCertificate(certificate));

                    // Create the  Drive service.
                    return new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                        ApplicationName = "Drive Authentication Sample",
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Unsupported Service accounts credentials.");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                
                throw new Exception("CreateServiceAccountDriveFailed", ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

code ripped from [ServiceAccount.cs](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Drive%20API/v3/ServiceAccount.cs)

Comment: dear DalmTo Thanks for your helping , but kindly this code required from each  user to enter his GMail account , i want to upload files to my account (centralize storage through GDrive)

Comment: Then you should be using a service account not Oauth2 authentication.   You probably should have added that requirement in your question.  The first part of my anwser explains why you are getting the error message you are getting.  I have updated the anwser with some code for using a service account instead.

Comment: Thanks DalmTo  for your helping, working fine but when view the uploaded file after the API reply with FileID cannot access it direct through https://docs.google.com/uc?id=MyNewFileID get me authorization error on chrome explorer  and cannot find it direct on google drive account , if you can help me , thanks in advance

Comment: your not going to be able to access a file using that link.  You need to have access to a file to be able to access it.   If the service account uploaded it then it owns the file and only it can access it.   Unless you have it grant your user permission to access it.

Comment: can you provide me with more details please

Comment: inorder to access a file you must have permission to access it.   The link you are trying to use first of all is probably incorrect second will not contain the permission need to access it.    try doing a file get an look for a download Link in the response

Comment: my need solution is allow users to uploads media (images , videos ) through my GDrive account , and i and others users can access this media, so that you recommended to me  the service account

Comment: You can not allow others to upload data to your personal Google Drive account.  They need to be authenticated and i dont recommend you giveing everyone the login and password to your drive account.  A service account can be granted access to write to your drive account.   Your either going to have to share the files with other users from your drive account. or request access to their drive account and upload the files their.   This is how drive works.  You cant access something you dont have permission to access.  Yes i would use a service account

Comment: okay ,  Thanks i worked done thought  different solution by create mission for the file to anyone can read it , it's working done and the users not need to login